# Swift function returning two different types

Tags: ios, swift, function

I need a function that can return either a `String` or an `Int` depending on the parameters entered eg:

```
func getValue (type: String) -> (String || Int) {  //this line is obviously wrong
    if type == "type1" {
        return "exampleString"
    }
    else if type == "type2"
        return 56
    }
}
```

Comment: In what context does it make sense to do so?

Comment: Use `Any` if you have to declare that function

Comment: *facepalm* of course thanks! didn't think of that

Comment: Instead of int You can return string that represent a number "56", and convert it to int in the reciver Int("56").

Comment: This seems like a case of the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MattWyeth Could you please vote on the answers, and accept one if you feel your question is satisfied?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Edit: I'm editing this answer, because I think my old answer is mostly just leading people down the wrong road.

The ability to return one of two (completely-unrelated) types might *sound* like it would solve your problem, but it **almost certainly does not**. Swift is a statically typed language, which means that it limits what you can do to a value, depending on its type (this limitation is beneficial, because you know this will always work!).

You can multiply `Int`s, and you can concatenate `String`s, but you can't multiply `String`s or concatenate `Int`s. But what if you had a value that was either a hypothetical `(Int || String)`? What could you do with that?

- Well you can't multiply, because what if it was a `String` underneath? That wouldn't make sense.
- You couldn't concatenate it either, because what if the underlying value was an `Int`? That wouldn't make sense, either.

The only thing that would be allowable, is to only do those things which are supported by *both* Int or String. And what is that exactly? Well, you could get the `description: String`, and that's... about it.

The modern solution to this problem is to describe the capabilities of the result using a protocol, and to return that. Here's an example:

```swift
protocol ModeOfTransport {
    func transport(cargo: String)
}

struct Car: ModeOfTransport {
    func transport(cargo _: String) {
        print("I'll put the light cargo in my trunk and drive it.")
    }
}

struct Train: ModeOfTransport {
    func transport(cargo: String) {
        print("I'll put attach the heavy cargo in a new car and pull it.")
    }
}

func getAppropriateModeOfTransport(cargoWeight: Int) -> ModeOfTransport {
    if cargoWeight < 500 {
        return Car()
    } else {
        return Train()
    }
}

let modeOfTransport = getAppropriateModeOfTransport(cargoWeight: 1234)
modeOfTransport.transport(cargo: "Sample Cargo")
```

---

Original answer:

You can use Enumeration

You can use an enumeration with associated  values to achieve the behaviour you're looking for. They're much like a nicer version of C's unions.

```
enum Foo { //TODO: Give me an appropriate name.
    case type1(String)
    case type2(Int)
    
    static func getValue(type: String) -> Foo {
        switch (type) {
            case "type1": return type1("exampleString")
            case "type2": return type2(56)
            default: fatalError("Invalid \"type\"");
        }
    }
}

let x = Foo.getValue(type: "type1")
```

This is actually very annoying, because the only way to do anything sensible with these values it to consume them conditionally, by switching on its type and responding accordingly:

```
switch x {
    case .type1(let string): funcThatExpectsString(string)
    case .type2(let int): funcThatExpectsInt(int)
}
```

If you're not careful, these `switch`es will consume your entire codebase. This is why I recommend the protocol-base approach above.

Comment: Is there a way to handle the return type being a protocol with `associatedtype`? e.g. change `ModeOfTransport` to this: `protocol ModeOfTransport { associatedtype CargoType; func transport(cargo: CargoType) }`

Comment: That's not a return type, that's the type of a parameter. In any case, I think you should open a new question for that, to get into more detail. Feel free to link it here

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem and I solved in this way (you can use default associated value introduced in Swift 5.1 and opaque return type)

```
class PersistanceHelper {

    enum PersistenceType {
        case userStatus(status: String = "")
        case firstAccess(isFirstAccess: Bool = true)
        case biometricsEnabled(isBiometricsEnabled: Bool = true)
        case notificationToken(token: String = "")

        func getKey() -> String {
            switch self {
            case .userStatus        : return "userStatusKey"
            case .firstAccess.      : return "firstAccessKey"
            case .biometricsEnabled : return "biometricsEnabledKey"
            case .notificationToken : return "notificationTokenKey"
            }
        }
    }

    static func save(_ objectType: PersistenceType) {
        switch objectType {
        case .userStatus(let payload), .notificationToken(let payload):
            UserDefaults.standard.set(payload, forKey: objectType.getKey())
        case .firstAccess(let payload), .biometricsEnabled(isBiometricsEnabled: let payload):
            UserDefaults.standard.set(payload, forKey: objectType.getKey())
        }
    }

    static func load<T>(_ objectType: PersistenceType) -> T? {
        UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: objectType.getKey()) as? T
    }

}
```

And then use it where you need...

```
PersistanceHelper.save(.notificationToken(token: "93028184-87be-4a62-bcc9-70ec08d6fe7e"))
PersistanceHelper.save(.biometricsEnabled(isBiometricsEnabled: true))

if let token: String = PersistanceHelper.load(.notificationToken()),
    let isBiometricEnabled: Bool = PersistanceHelper.load(.biometricsEnabled()) {
    print(token)
    print(isBiometricEnabled)
}
```

The enums with associated values allow to write a self explaining code... at least to me :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a tuple with optional values then create code to unwrap them accordingly.

The type `Any` should be used sparingly, the fact that you know it's either a `String` or `Int` means the tuple could be the most appropriate solution in your use case.

```
func someFuction(type: String) -> (String?, Int?) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Unwrap optional switch example:

```
let sometuple: (string: String?, int: Int?) = ("Hi", 10)

switch sometuple {
    case let (.some(s), .some(i)):
        print("String: \(s), Int: \(i)")

    case let (.some(s), nil):
        print(s)

    case let (nil, .some(i)):
        print(i)

    case (nil, nil):
        print("Nothing")

}
//prints "String: Hi, Int: 10"
```

The reason this works is because `Optional` is an enum:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case some(x:T)
    case none
}
```

Comment: yes if you could show me how to unwrap it that would be great

Comment: This isn't an appropriate use of tuples/optionals. It's wasteful memory-wise, doesn't scale well for many types, and it a pain to unwrap.

Comment: @MattWyeth added my switch optional unwrapping example

Comment: @hoolioo The `case` statements can be simplified to: `let (s?, i?)`, `let (s?, nil)`, and `let (nil, i?)`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov true. But I wanted to be explicit. Thanks for the heads up tho :)

Comment: 2^n cases for unwraps