# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred, Generic Error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a function to choose which implementation is good, like that:

```
// As a BaseProtocol
protocol BaseProtocol {
    
}

// SeniorProtocol with associatedtype
protocol SeniorProtocol {
    associatedtype S
}

// First implementation of SeniorProtocol
struct SeniorImpl1:SeniorProtocol {
    typealias S = BaseProtocol
    init() {}
}

// Second implementation of SeniorProtocol
struct SeniorImpl2:SeniorProtocol {
    typealias S = BaseProtocol
    init() {}
}

// The function 
func whichImpl<T: SeniorProtocol>() -> T{
    if Int.random(in: 0 ... 5) < 3 {
        return SeniorImpl1() as! T
    }
    else {
        return SeniorImpl2() as! T
    }
}
```

Finally, when I run

```
var c = whichImpl()
```

I got this error: “Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred”.
It seems that the compiler does't know what T is.
How can I solve it? I just want to do what the code written in whichImpl()

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Your use of generics is completely flawed, since you aren't returning a generic type, but rather a concrete type, hence the compiler error.

Comment: I just want to return a struct that conform protocol 'SeniorProtocol' with conditions. Because 'SeniorProtocol' has associatedtype, it can not be a return value.

Comment: You gotta do what standard Swift libraries do: Create `AnySenior`(something like [`AnyCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anycollection)) type-erased wrapper, and return it.

Comment: I fear this is not possible (and I am not sure if this would be a good idea at all). user28434's solution could be a good one. Using the `some` keyword isn't an option either: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html#ID614 . This question may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034034/swift-function-returning-two-different-types . I think it would be the best if you provide us with more context, so that we can look if there is a better solution for your case.

Answer (score -2):

Since your method returns a value of the generic type T, then you have to let Swift know which concrete type you want your `c` variable to be to make Swift's type checking system works. In your case, simply give your `c` a concrete type like this will make the error pass away.

```
var c: Int = whichImpl()
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be the solution, because `Int` does not conform to `SeniorProtocol` (which is a requirement for the generic type `T`). So this won't compile. Furthermore, this would mean that you are force-casting from either `SeniorImpl1` or `SeniorImpl2` to `Int` (because `T` is `Int`), which will always fail because they aren't related any way.

Comment: Thanks, but T which conform [SeniorProtocol]  can only be SeniorImpl1 or  SeniorImpl2 in this case.

Comment: Just want to clarify that my answer is just an option that we can give the `c` a concrete type. It's not necessarily an `Int`. In case you don't want to do so, you can try out some type erasure solutions. But I'm not sure whether it works in your case or not.