# how to change variable type based on logic in swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to declare one variable when the logic is true. For more text, I need to interact with some element and verify if the view is up and down through UI testing. The process and defined element is under the property of each view. However, based on the logic, I need to interact and verify different views.

For example, if `request.response` is `true`, I need to verify ViewA. Otherwise, I need to interact with ViewB. The following code is ok. But I would like to clean it up by setting up a local variable to represent the view and reuse the code for interaction/verification.

```
if request.response {
    // tap ViewA button One
    // tap ViewA button Two
    // verify ViewA context one
    // verify ViewA context two
    // verify ViewA context three
    // tap ViewA button Three
    // verify ViewA is dismiss
} else {
    // tap ViewB button One
    // tap ViewB button Two
    // verify ViewB context one
    // verify ViewB context two
    // verify ViewB context three
    // tap ViewB button Three
    // verify ViewB is dismiss
}
```

clean up

```
var interactedView = ViewB
if request.response {
    interactedView = ViewA
}
// tap interactedView button One
// tap interactedView button Two
// verify interactedView context one
// verify interactedView context two
// verify interactedView context three
// tap interactedView button Three
// verify interactedView is dismiss
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what you're trying to achieve here? How do you intend to use `changeTypeVariable` if it's a `String`, and how do you intend to use it if it's an `Int`? Why does it need to be one variable, instead of two? More details will help provide a useful answer.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem.  What's the underlying goal for wanting to do this?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: it is for UI testing. I have bunch of code that needs to interact with element and verify if view the up or down. The Int or String types refer here as two different view. i do not want to copy and paste

Comment: For ordinary unit test I prefer to not be too clever and try generalise and extract common test code into functions etc since it makes the test harder to understand, it introduces some logic that might be contain bugs itself and the tests are harder to maintain if the tested code changes. Simple, self-contained tests are better imo even if it means a lot of duplicate code. I assume it's similar for UI tests.

Comment: @jacobcan118 Could you please give more context on your original problem? I'm finding it hard to picture from your terse description. I'm having a hard time imaging why a UI test might need to reassign a variable of one view type with a variable of another view type. I bet there's a way to circumvent that entirely

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** the question has changed a bit.

Now it is clear that the two types you want are views. I'm assuming that they both conform to the SiftUI protocol `View`.

You simply need to declare your variable aa anything conforming to `View`

```
var interactedView: View = ViewB
```

If the views have common funcs/properties that you want to be able to use after this, you'll need to declare them to conform to another protocol that has those constraints e.g.

```
protocol MyTestProtocol
{
    func tapButton()
}

extension ViewA: MyTestProtocol 
{
    func tapButton() { ... }
}

extension ViewB: MyTestProtocol 
{
    func tapButton() { ... }
}

var interactedView: MyTestProtocol = ViewB
```

---

Original answer

> I would like to declare one variable when the logic is true, it will be `Int` type. otherwise it would be `String`

This is not possible. Once you have declared a variable with a particular type, it keeps that type for as long as you are in its scope. There are ways around this though depending on what you *really* want to do.

If the `Int` value is only used inside the `if` you can simply declare a new variable. This variable (if it has the same name) is said to shadow the variable in the outer scope.

```
var changeTypeVariable: String = "I am original String"
if request.response {
    var changeTypeVariable: Int = 1000
    // The variable is now an Int and can be used wherever an Int is used
    // It goes away at the end of this if block
}
// The variable is now a String. It is no longer shadowed.
```

If you are likely to be using the variable elsewhere and passing it around, the cleanest solution is to use an `enum` with associated values

```
enum ChangeType
{
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

var changeTypeVariable = ChangeType.string("I am original String")
if request.response {
    changeTypeVariable = ChangeType.int(1000)
}
```

To use it, the simplest way is to use a `switch`

```
switch changeTypeVariable
{
case .string(let stringVariable):
    // Do stuff with stringVariable
case .int(let intVariable):
    // Do stuff with intVariable
}
```

Comment: Using an enum to make a union of two completely unrelated types is [one of my most regrettable answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40034233/3141234). People reach for it thinking that it'll solve their problem, but it almost certainly is leading them down the wrong path, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Alexander I don't agree. There are many situations where you want to be able to deal with unrelated types. A model of JSON comes to mind where a JSON entity can be a string or a number or a boolean etc. It's probably not the right answer in view of the rewritten question but declaring variables as protocols comes with its owen drawbacks.

Comment: @JeremyP Oh don't get me wrong, enums with associated values are massively useful, and I have tons of them in my own codebase. My worry is that it's often times it's the first thing new programmers think they need, but would be better served by having a better architecture, or protocols that more clearly capture the semantics of what exactly the unioned types have in common. Worse yet, it nudges newbs down the road of data-and-procedures (without the performance concern to warrant that), rather than polymorphism, and just blows up their code bases with `switch` statements everywhere

Comment: @JeremyP As a good example, I've seen a case where a dev wanted to implement a calculator, but wanted to be able to handle both string and number inputs. Rather than parsing strings into numbers, and using numbers as the sole cannonical representation for their calculator to operate on, they were trying to implement a function like `func add(lhs: StringOrInt, rhs: StringOrInt) -> StringOrInt { /* wat? */ }`. I feel like I gave that dev a end-heavy loaded gun that points at their feet.

Comment: @Alexander You can't blame yourself for somebody else misapplying a useful pattern. If there's a legit reason (such as the JSON example I mentioned) it is not negated by other people being stupid.

Comment: I'm not so sure. It's not about stupidity, just newbs who are just reaching out trying to grab the first most obvious-looking solution to their _immediate_ problem. The appeal of `!` is similar: they tried to use an optional value where a non-optional was needed, and just tacking on `!` makes the compiler stop yelling. It solves the first immediate hurdle, but falls apart on step 2 or 3. Enums have a similar often-misleading allure. I think it's worthwhile to try to first understand the underlying problem, and tailor a solution that's appropriate to it.

Comment: @Alexander Useful patterns are also not negated by other people's ignorance.